Who chose Stephen to be a deacon?
Who is "they" in "and they chose Stephen"?  Was it the multitude, or the apostles?
Acts 6:5 KJV
‭

And‭ the saying‭ pleased‭‭‭ the whole‭ multitude‭: and‭ they chose‭‭
Stephen‭, a man‭ full‭ of faith‭ and‭ of the Holy‭ Ghost‭, and‭
Philip‭, and‭ Prochorus‭, and‭ Nicanor‭, and‭ Timon‭, and‭ Parmenas‭,
and‭ Nicolas‭ a proselyte‭ of Antioch‭:‭

It seems like the 'they' might be the multitude because of verse 6 - "Whom‭ they set‭‭ before‭ the apostles".

The grammar of this verse, Acts 6:5, is very uncomplicated.  Let me set it out clearly:

Acts 6:2 - the 12 apostles call a meeting of the πλῆθος (pleros) multitude of disciples, ie, all believers
Acts 6:5a - the multitude was pleased with the suggestion to appoint Spirit-motivated deacons
Acts 6:5b - "they" chose, ie, the multitude chose, presumably guided by the Holy Spirit.

Now, we get a little more information about how this may have worked in two more places where the verb χειροτονέω (cheirotoneó = "elect by show of hands") is used, viz (Dottard's literal translation):

Acts 14:23 - Now, having elected for them in every church, elders, having prayed with fasting, they committed them to the Lord in whom they believed.
2 Cor 8:19 - now, not only that, but also having elected by the churches our fellow-traveler, with grace ...

The verb cheirotoneó is taken from the Roman senate as verb used to elect officials to office.


“Then the twelve called the multitude of the disciples unto them, and said, It is not reason that we should leave the word of God, and serve tables. Wherefore, brethren, look ye out among you seven men of honest report, full of the Holy Ghost and wisdom, whom we may appoint over this business.” (Act 6:2-3, KJV)

I see a process of selection in the narrative.

"The twelve called the multitude of disciples....". Here the twelve called all the believers together.

The twelve ordered that twelve people should be sought after amongst them. I guess a committee may have been set up to make the selection process. Not every disciple has the skill for selection. It will take disciples with certain integrity to make the selection.

Once the selected disciples were done, the twelve 'appointed' them. I believe appointments were subject to the approval of the twelve.

The church prayed over them as it was customary within the church at the time. I guess the appointment was similar to that of Paul and Barnabas who were prayed for or just as Timothy was prayed for by the laying on of hands.


Conclusion:
The disciples did the selection by looking for seven men amongst them. Perhaps, they may be more than seven so that the twelve could trim them down.
The twelve appointed the seven deacons based on the church custom at the time.

Verse 3 gives us the answer:

Wherefore, brethren, look ye out among you seven men of honest report, full of the Holy Ghost and wisdom, whom we may appoint over this business.

Or, as the ESV translates it "pick out from among you".
Therefore, the apostles instructed the multitude to make the selection.
